# How to get console output(in code) after running configurations in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to start another launch configurations depending on output from executing first launch configurations. So there is a way to get console output from this launch?

Something like this:

```
 Launch launch = (Launch) configurations[0].launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, console);
 if(launch.output){
   configurations[1].launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, console);
 }
```

For example first launch configuration is a maven project, and I need to check if build is succesfully or it failed.

I have following code:

```
Launch launch = (Launch) configurations[0].launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE,
                            new NullProgressMonitor());
                    final IProcess[] processes = launch.getProcesses();
                    IDebugEventSetListener listener = new IDebugEventSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void handleDebugEvents(DebugEvent[] events) {
                            for(DebugEvent e : events){
                                for(int i = 0; i < processes.length; i++){
                                    if(e.getKind() == DebugEvent.TERMINATE && e.getSource() == processes[i]){
                                        try {
                                            --------To check here if console contains Build Failed--------
                                            configurations[1].launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE,
                                                    new NullProgressMonitor());
                                        } catch (CoreException e1) {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    };
                    DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners` extension point to match patterns in console output:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners">
  <consolePatternMatchListener
        class="com.example.ExampleConsolePatternMatcher"
        id="com.example.ExampleConsolePatternMatcher"
        regex=".*foo.*">
     <enablement>
        <test property="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleTypeTest" value="exampleConsole"/>
     </enablement>
  </consolePatternMatchListener>
</extension>
```

You can use the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers` extension point to listen to lines output by processes of a given process type:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers">
  <consoleLineTracker
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javadocexport.JavadocConsoleLineTracker"
        processType="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javadocProcess"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javadocexport.JavadocConsoleLineTracker">
  </consoleLineTracker>
</extension>
```

Comment: and how I should connect this with launch process in code?

Comment: These extension points are active all the time. You will have to save the information about the launch somewhere that they can access to check if they need to do anything.

Comment: I understand this, but in the code, how to get console output to compare with some string?

Comment: If you mean the extension point code this is fully documented in the help on the extension point. For console line tracker, for example, you must implement `IConsoleLineTracker` and the `lineAppended` method is called when text is added to the console.